# WildFly / JBoss request timed out message on management console of domain mode while starting the server instance

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

"Your request timed out" message on management console of WildFly domain mode while starting the server instance.

- Its' not clear that whether an operation like server start-up or deployment has been succeeded or not.
- It requires two or three restart commands from the management GUI before the domain controller correctly displays the running status of WildFly instances.
- I found that "request timed out" message appears after cca 20-21 seconds when I do restart server instance.

I use WildFly version 10.1.0.Final in Domain mode.

Comment: Did you check the log files?

Comment: @TT. Yes I did but there is no information about that.

Comment: I am not working on WildFly yet, but in JBoss 7.1.3 you have two log files, one of them being `boot.log` (the other being `server.log`). Do you see that log file, or any such log file that would contain boot logging?

Comment: There's no such thing as a separate boot log anymore. The server.log has everything, but I really don't see anything about timeout. I will try to set logging to TRACE and we will see.

Comment: So I set log level from INFO to TRACE and unfortunately I don't see any helpful information.

Comment: Do you have the same issue using the CLI ?

Comment: @ehsavoie When I use CLI, everything seems OK but there is a strange(undefined) output like "outcome" => "success","result" => undefined, "server-groups" => undefined. I think this issue appears only with WildFly web console.